# Waiting for function to finish before closing the window using window.onbeforeunload

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, hta

I need your help,

It seems that when I close the window (IE 11), the confirm box pops up and I click on the OK button, the function wants to run, but the window closes down before the function gets a chance to finish (saving a record to a DB). How can the code be modified such that, it will give the function imts_save_changes() a chance to finish its DB operations before closing down the window?

Here is the markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

<style type="text/css">

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

window.onbeforeunload = function() { return test() }

function test() {

    if (confirm("would you like to run the last function before closing the window?")) {

         imts_save_changes()

         alert("record saved")

    }
}

</script>

</head>

<body></body>

</html>
```

The code in question:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() { return test() }

function test() {

    if (confirm("would you like to run the last function before closing the window?")) {

         imts_save_changes()

         alert("record saved")

    }
}
```

Comment: You would need to just cancel the navigation and use the onbeforeunload with their normal message.

Comment: It's not possible for Javascript to prevent closing the window. This is a security feature, malware used to keep the window open until the user allowed it to do its damage.

Comment: @barmar HTAs don't care much about security ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `confirm` closing the window fired by `onbeforeunload` event, it is immediately closed; you cannot cancel subsequent action (real closing). All you can do is to warn user, in this case about unsaved changes and to give him chance not to confirm action.

I'm not 100% sure, but I think that `alert` and `confirm` function freezes DOM so nothing can happen before user interaction.

IMO, you should change the design of your app.